# Fixing Kubuntu 18.04 resolution

Tags: kubuntu, display-resolution

I've been trying numerous guides for a while now but nothing seems to work. I'm running a gtx 970 w/ the open source Nouveau driver. I did the whole cvt 1920 1080 60 thing and copied the text:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

However, one of the problems I'm having is that it always responds with

```
Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Also, I'm unable to find the name of the output, so even if I got past this step I wouldn't be able to assign it to an output

Output from

```
sudo xrandr -q



    Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 
    1280 x 1024
   default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00* 
   1920x1080_60.00 (0x2ca) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

As far as I can tell, there's no output name in there. Anybody got any suggestions? Thanks!